# Get rows from result step and Get Varaibles usage in Pentaho data Integeration

Tags: pentaho, pdi

can any one provide example for both get variables and get rows from result step in pentaho data integration.

1. I have a job with two transformations.
2. First transformation take sample input and genrate sample output and a the end i have copy rows to result step.
3. My 2nd transformation has get rows from result step and a dummy.
4. When I run my job i am not gettion output in the dummy.
5. I even tried with the Get Variables Step instead of Get rows from result step even though i am not getting the output.
6. so,how can i solve this.

Comment: Check that on the 2nd transformation, under Advanced, the checkboxes "clear the list of result rows before execution", "copy previous rows to args", "copy previous rows to parameters" and "execute for every input row" aren't checked. When you run the job you should be able to see in the log a count of rows READ and WRITTEN by each step of each transformation. If the Dummy has a R=10 and W=10, for example, that says it received 10 rows from the get rows from result step. Please paste a screenshot of your ktrs, job and execution logs.

Answer (score 4):

So, to make the answer as graphic and abstract as possible, let's assume we have a main job, and two transformations inside it (they could also be two sub-jobs).

Job:

[image: Main job]

**Read Process Parameters** would end like this:

[image: Copy rows to results]

**Do something nice** would have the following settings:

Under **Advanced** tab, 'Copy previous results to parameters?' check-box would be checked;
If you wished the transformation to execute for each row, you would check the 'Execute for every input row?' check-box ;
[image: Parameters]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should uncheck "copy previous result to parameter", this make the result(output by the previous trans) disapear ( anyway ,can't be get by "get rows from result" )